# URI images - Database column v/s class file

Tags: database, class, optimization, yii2

I am developing a web app that populates a different image on every page, based on some logic. There are 20,000 images stored as URI in my database in a read only table.

Would it be better if I populate the 20,000 URI values as a static class file instead? So, instead of returning the uri itself to the AJAX call that displays the image on the web page, I can return the image id and the uri can be pulled from a constant JSON variable.

I plan to deploy my website on Google GCP, and was wondering if there would be any speed improvements by avoiding data transfer, pulling of a text column from the table, and possible caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing your Image data in JSON file can increase your speed, unless you do not have big file. When it comes to search inside JSON file you will lose in speed comparing to Database, because in order to get needed info, you need to load whole file and then with loop make iteration. Which means you will lose in performance.

Storing your image urls in database is better solution, because the more data you will have the better performance you will have comparing to static file. Moreover you can index your table which also increase speed.

So my advice, Use Database not JSON, because you have quite more data